# Calling application.exit and pass value to FormClosing

Tags: c#, winforms

When my application loads, I check to see if there are any updates.  If there is an update, we prompt the user if they want to update.

If they say yes, we launch the updater and need to close our application but on the FormClosing we ask "are you sure you want to close?".

How do I pass a value to the FormClosing event, so I can skip the "are you sure" messagebox?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason?view=net-5.0

Comment: You can't _pass_ data to the `FormClosing` event handler. You can look at `CloseReason`. See duplicate. If that doesn't suit you, you can create a `bool` field that indicates whether the prompt should be shown. Set it to `true` by default, then set it to `false` if you want to suppress the prompt.

Comment: You can use a boolean variable that has global scope to indicate whether there's an update being done, such as `IsUpdate`.  If you're going to do an update, set that variable to true. In your `FormClosing` event, test the value of that variable `if !IsUpdate`, and don't call `MessageBox` if it's true.

Comment: Thank you, the duplicate using the CloseReason is exactly what I was looking for.  Worked like a charm.